# Joining 2 columns in 1 table to 1 column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have the following tables

```
Employee
    ID QueueID OverrideQueueID
    1    1         NULL
    2    2          3
    3    1          3
    4    4          NULL

Queue
    ID
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

I need to join these tables together. Basically the join needs to look to see if there is an OverrideQueueID, if so, use that OverrideQueueID in the join to the QueueTable, if not use the QueueID in the join. The QueueID will always exists but the OverrideQueueID will sometimes be NULL. This is going to be millions of records joined to a table with about 10 records in it, so I didn't want to go the COALESCE route as I have seen performance degradation there in the past in using functions in joins. I assume if I went the COALESCE route a table scan would always be performed to generate the value from the COALESCE.

This is similar to the below question I put out earlier, but now I have 1 table joining to 1 table instead of 1 table conditionally joining to multiple tables. I have made some progress from the original question.
       [[Conditional join to two different tables based on 2 columns in 1 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569626/conditional-join-to-two-different-tables-based-on-2-columns-in-1-table][1])

Comment: In that case, revise your original question.  You have multiple suggestions from people already familiar with your situation.

Comment: There is already multiple answers on my original question, this completely changes the question into a new question going this route.

Comment: I would just do the join like `table t on coalesce(t.OverrideQId, t.QueueId) = a.ParameterId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COALESCE or ISNULL in the join is nonetheless the way to go.
Analyse the execution plan of your query if the performances are not up to your expectations and edit yout post with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the COALESCE function to populate a temp table with the employee ID and the corrected QueueID, then index that table.

Then join to the indexed temp table instead.  Whether this will be faster than using a function in your join is best determined experimentally.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this query returns what you're looking for:

```
SELECT E.*
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Queue Q ON Q.ID = ISNULL(E.OverrideQueueID, E.QueueID)
```

Not sure about the performance of this query in case of hudge volume of data.

Hope this will help you for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Select  * from
Queue q
Inner join 
( select *, isnull(orderedqueueid, queueid) as joinedqueueid from employee) as e
On q.id = e.joined QueueId;

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use the Case statement... as below...

```
select 
e.ID as E_ID,
e.QueueID,
e.OverrideQueueID,
q.ID as Q_ID
From Employee e 
Join Queue q 
    On (Case When e.OverrideQueueID is Not Null Then e.OverrideQueueID Else e.QueueID End) = q.ID
```

2nd Alternative

```
Select 
e.ID as E_ID,
e.QueueID,
Q.ID as Q_ID
(
select ID,QueueID from Employee Where OverrideQueueID is NULL
Union All
select ID,OverrideQueueID as QueueID from Employee Where OverrideQueueID is Not NULL
) e 
  Join Queue Q on e.QueueID = Q.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have proper Indexes on employee table...you can go for CTE to do separate joins SQLs, both for Null and NotNull versions and do union all at the outer most Select.

Answer (score 0):

To address your perf concerns, another option would be to add a computed, persisted column to the employee table, then index this column and do all joins against it instead of either QueueId or OverrideQueueId. For example:

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD ActiveQueueId AS COALESCE(OverrideQueueId, QueueId) PERSISTED;
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Employee_ActiveQueueId ON dbo.Employee (ActiveQueueId);
```